# Google Script Copying part of a cell to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Goal: Trying to copy part of some text from one cell on a spread sheet and pasting it on to another one.

I am still new to Javascript to please forgive if im going about this all wrong.

So on one spread sheet some information gets populated automatically from a service I use. I want to take part of that information and copy and paste it onto another spread sheet.

For this example the date gets populated in the cell A1 "February 28, 2017 at 10:38AM." I want to only copy the date February 28, 2017 and paste it onto another google sheet.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234");
 var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Text");
 var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Bills"); 
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D4");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var string1 = cell.getValue();
 var string2 = string1.split(" ", 2);
 var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("J4");

 string2.copyTo(target_range);

 //Logger.log(string2);

}
```

The error I receive when i do this is:
TypeError: Cannot find function copyTo in object February,28,. (line 13, file "Test")

This maybe something simple i jsut cont figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .setValue() to set the value of the range. So to set your range to the value in string2 you would replace line 13 with:

target_range.setValue(string2);

See the [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) for some examples of scripts.  Especially the Workflows and end-to-end examples.

Comment: When i do this its only doing February not February 28. Is this because im splitting it wrong?

Comment: You are splitting it on spaces.  I didn't look at that part of the code.  Split it at " at "  like this: `var string2 = string1.split(" at ");` and string2 will be an array of the items on each side of " at " so  the line I gave becomes `target_range.setValue(string2[0]);`